# Editor heartbeat gives a 409 - Conflict sometimes

Tags: bug, asking-questions, editor, live-refresh

Yesterday, while writing a question, I saw errors in the console. They were caused by a failed heartbeat call by the editor, which returned a 409:

[image]

I'm not sure under which circumstances they happen, but today I was able to reproduce it while having the Ask question page open in two different tabs. The request itself is a simple POST call to https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask with the following payload:

```
text=body+of+the+question&title=&tagnames=bug+asking-questions+editor&fkey=never+share+your+fkey
```

Comment: [Can repro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ0K0.png). Workaround: don't ask multiple questions (have the `/ask` window open) on multiple sites *at the same time*. You're running into rate-limiting. Each window has a separate heartbeat and the network is telling you to stop badgering it.

Comment: @Mast huh, so we found the DDoS attacker, finally! :-D